# How to remove prefix="" from <html> tag?

Tags: wordpress

How can i remove prefix= attribute from this `<html amp lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://mop.me/ns#" class="no-js">` by using hook. This is coming from Yoast SEO plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be removed just by some hook, because it is added in a class constructor of WPSEO_OpenGraph class.